# jQuery: $.each() recursion empties the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, recursion

I have a json object that has `key:value` pairs and also objects that are formatted the same, `key:value`

I am trying to output the `key` and `value` in the same loop like so

```
 populateUpdateForm: function(data) {

    // console.log(typeof(data));
    // console.log(data);

    $.each(data, function(i, v){

        if ( typeof(v) == 'object' ) {
            populateUpdateForm(v);
            // return false;
        }

        console.log(i, v);

    });

}
```

As long as the current `v` is a string, it outputs it correctly, but as soon as I hit an object and start the loop again, the `console.log(data)` is `empty` even if the `typeof()` shows an object.

Any way I can fix this ?

Thank you

**EDIT** With or without the breaking of the loop results in the same error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` in the jquery.min.js file

**EDIT2** Here https://jsfiddle.net/7rLesm4y/ is a jsfiddle that is the copy/paste of my code. I am using the same jQuery version, but on localhost I get the error while on jsfiddle it works as I intended.

Comment: it should be array instead of object to iterate again.

Comment: @Braj `$.each` works on objects, too.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for correcting me

Comment: Why are you breaking the recursion with `return false` on the first object you find?   (not sure about your actual problem, but that looks wrong)

Comment: @Alnitak it is not breaking, the `each` loop will continue.

Comment: @xpy no, it won't - `return false` in a `$.each` callback will break the loop.

Comment: @Alnitak That is commented on the actual code, forgot to comment it here also. The actual error in Chrome console is "Cannot read property 'length' of null" on the jquery.min.js file

Comment: I suggest you just make a simple test case (on jsfiddle.net, perhaps) where you create a simple nested object and then just try your code.  I can't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: Actually `typeof(null) == 'object'` https://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/6pm0xded/1/ so `null` values will try to continue through the loop but won't be able to iterate through the `$.each` loop.

Comment: @xpy it does seem likely that the problem is GIGO.  The code is otherwise fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/1tmekafo/

Comment: Ive tried this and it works as expected (https://jsfiddle.net/btp1rvge/) Reproduce the problem in a minimal example.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/7rLesm4y/ is an exact copy of my code. On my localhost I get the error, on jsfiddle it seems to work.

Comment: your _code_ is (mostly) fine, it's the _data_ that's the problem.  You need to prevent it from recursing `if (v === null)`

Comment: @Alnitak That was it, I solved it by breaking the loop if the data is null. Do you have any recommendations on improving the code ? Thank you

Comment: I would just do `if (v !== null && typeof v === 'object') { recurse ... } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `null` values and the `$.each` loop. While it seems to work in `jQuery v2.2.0` it throws an error on older versions, `TypeError: obj is null` on FF and `Cannot read property 'length' of null` on Chrome.

Comment: Indeed, as Alnitak also mentioned, I also needed to check if the object is null. Now it's working fine. Thank you